# Are there any ways to refresh a partial view without using jQuery in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I found a solution to refresh my partial view (a table with some data) using jQuery, calling an action from the controller and changing the view model, when clicking a button, selecting an option from a select box, etc. But I wonder if there are any other ways to do that, maybe something from ASP.NET MVC5, without using external libraries.

Comment: You could always replace the jQuery with "native" or "vanilla" JavaScript

Comment: Yes, but I was searching for a way to do that in MVC, with C#

Comment: Hypothetically speaking, if MVC were to have such a feature, what do you think it would use under the hood to make that functionality work? Probably vanilla JS, perhaps if it was implemented a long time ago it might have used jQuery.

Comment: Why are you searching for this in the first place? What problem are you hoping to solve by finding a direct answer to your question?

Comment: @mason I wanted to know if there are alternatives

Answer (score 1):

You can use Signal R. For more information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr

Comment: SignalR is part of ASP.NET, but not part of MVC 5 (though they can be used together). And SignalR also [relies on jQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc).